# Why in Landau the spherical harmonics had a multiple of $i^l$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, conventions, definition, spherical-harmonics

Quote Landau The Classical Theory of Fields Page 100 Equation 41.11

$$\displaystyle
Y_{lm}(\theta,\phi)=(-1)^m i^l \sqrt{\frac{2l+1}{4\pi}   \frac{(l-m)!}{(l+m)!}  } P_l^{|m|}(\cos\theta)  e^{im\phi} $$
for $m\geq 0$ and 
$$Y_{l,-|m|}(\theta,\phi)= (-1)^{l-m} Y_{l,|m|}^*.$$

Could anyone explain to me why there's a $i^l$ in the definition of the [spherical harmonics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics)? I have checked half dozens of webpage and books, but they all stick with the real coefficients. Why there's a $i^l$?

Comment: Do they define the $P^m_l$ somewhere? might be an unusual convention for them that then propagates into the $Y_l^m$.

Comment: @jacob1729 Quote: footnotes: "In accordance with the definition used in quantum mechanics".  It's just the one without the Condon–Shortley phase.